# Type safety between JS and iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, protocol-buffers, hybrid-mobile-app

Right now we have javascript application that gets pulled into a WKWebView. This application fires out messages via events. We wrote an intermediary layer that listens for those events, does some parsing and delivers the result to iOS to do some native work.

This works pretty well; however, we are a little worried (and have already seen) type safety issues arise. If the JS API changes then iOS needs to adapt and there is no contract in place really to confirm everything will remain working.

We came up with 2 ideas:

- more unit tests to enforce the contract
- using some sort of protocol buffer type strategy to ensure schema

Is there a better way? Is there a good protocol buffer example that does something like this?

Comment: What kind of types are we talking about here? Shouldn't the only thing you're communicating be JSON objects, and thus dictionaries, arrays, and primitives?

Comment: @quark of course, types are still less strict in JS. If you change an int to a string then your interface will probably break.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is send all primitives as strings, and then parse them based on the key name. e.g. `numUnits` will always be an int, or maybe make some naming convention that would make it obvious what type the value is.

You could even make each value consist of 2 key value pairs, one for the value, one for the type. That would bloat the JSON but would make it type safe.

e.g. `{"numUnits":{"value":"5", "type":"int"}}`